# Why I can't access to RunCommandLineApplicationAsync?

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface, console-application

I'm trying to build `CLI`. I took an example [here](https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-command-line-interface-cli-program-with-net-core-428c4c85221)

And in Program class author use `return await builder.RunCommandLineApplicationAsync<TestCmd>(args);`

Like a start point of program, but when i'm trying to do the same i have an error: [image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I figured out why, because i thougth that it's from Microsoft.Hosting, but i need to intall this package: McMaster.Extensions.Hosting.CommandLine.

Close please this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why, because i thougth that it's from Microsoft.Hosting, but i need to intall this package: McMaster.Extensions.Hosting.CommandLine.
Close please this topic